# Can't add an entry to a table with Many-to-Many relationships

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to add an `Art` object and getting this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class Source->sources'. Original exception was: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Source.arts - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

Here's my code:

```
art_tags = db.Table('art_tags',
    db.Column('art_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('arts.id')),
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.id'))
)

art_categories = db.Table('art_categories',
    db.Column('art_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('arts.id')),
    db.Column('category_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categories.id'))
)

class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    arts = db.relationship('Art', secondary=art_tags, backref='tags', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Tag id={} name="{}">'.format(self.id, self.name)

class Source(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sources'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    arts = db.relationship('Art', backref='source', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Source id={} name="{}"'.format(self.id, self.name)

class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    arts = db.relationship('Art', secondary=art_categories, backref='categories', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Category id={} name="{}">'.format(self.id, self.name)

class Art(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'arts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    original = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False, unique=True)
    preview = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Art id={}>'.format(self.id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I managed this thing to be working.

I've created missing columns on an `Art` object:

```
class Art(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'arts'
    ...
    source_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('sources.id'))
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=art_tags, back_populates='arts')
    categories = db.relationship('Category', secondary=art_categories, back_populates='arts')
    ...
```

Then I've changed all `backref=` to `back_populates=` in other classes (tables):

```
class Tag(db.Model):
    ...
    arts = db.relationship('Art', secondary=art_tags, back_populates='tags')
    ...

class Source(db.Model):
    ...
    # Here we have to leave backref, because this isn't Many-to-Many, but Many-to-One
    arts = db.relationship('Art', backref='source')
    ...

class Category(db.Model):
    ...
    arts = db.relationship('Art', secondary=art_categories, back_populates='categories')
    ...
```

And after that, the `Art` object created succesfully.